# Authentication between Keycloak and Backend-Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

We use Keycloak to secure our Spring Boot based Java Backend Services. Every endpoint is secured and a bearer token is expected inside the authorization header for each request. Keycloak then validates and verifies the token. So far so good.

During the registration process inside Keycloak (we use the authorization code flow), we have different use cases in which Keycloak have to approach our Java Backend for instance to validate an access code. I would love to use the same mechanism to secure those endpoints that are exclusively approached by Keycloak. I am wondering if it is a bad idea to use a keycloak user to send an http from a keycloak spi to our spring boot backend and then ask keycloak if the given JWT is valid. This feels like a chicken egg problem.

This feels like a common problem. What is the recommended authentication/authorization process for this kind of service to service communication? I was thinking about a technical keycloak user, that is managed inside keycloak for this purpose. I am aware of the Keycloak REST API that provides an endpoint to retrieve a token for credentials. Since I am implementing custom SPIs in keycloak, I am looking for a way to generate a token programmatically. I was able to find the right Keycloak library. Does someone know how to do that?

Here are my question:

1. How can I secure requests that I would like to send from keycloak to our backend?
2. How can I generate a Token inside Keycloak without using the Keycloak REST API (since I am implementing custom Keycloak SPIs)
3. Is there another way to secure my backend for technical users without using keycloak?

Best regards
Michel